# IOS: Is it possible preserve the State of UIViewController in Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Am developing an IOS app. Where i need to make some images upload to server. Am using `NSURLSession` and `uploadTaskWithRequest` to do this. Every thing is working fine in normal way. My requirement user wants to store some post with more than 10 images in app using database SQLLite. And later show all the stored posts in `UITableView` with button for each `UITableViewCell`. When user tap on each button it should start uploading each POST to server. So I thought i should persist my `UIViewController` in `AppDelegate` so the process of uploading should not be killed when user go to another view controllers.

My Problem: When user close the app the process is in which `UIViewController` POST uploading is Stoping. So i would like to know how to keep my UIViewController live even in app go close or go into background.

Is there any better way to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: You're thinking about the problem backwards.  A view controller should not be the center of attention but a tool used by the real code.  The state that the view controller displays should be maintained elsewhere, and the view controller should query that state to see what to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some better ways!

1. Use a singleton.  In my apps, I'll usually create a class called "DataHandler" that handles all of the NSURLSession/CoreData/etc stuff so all I have to do is

   ```
   [DataHandler uploadImages:images];
   ```

and when I need the information back I'll call

```
    self.tableData = [DataHandler lastUploadedImages];
```

This way I don't have to worry if my view controller is still alive.

2. Have the AppDelegate do the NSURLSession stuff.  You already know the AppDelegate is persisted so why not just have that guy do it! Here is an example:

   ```
   UIApplication *sharedApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = [sharedApplication delegate];
   // this is the method you would add to your AppDelegate.  Make sure to
   // import your AppDelegate's header file so your ViewController can
   // call the method.
   [appDelegate uploadImages:images];
   ```

Comment: OK. I have one question is it possible to keep UIViewController active even when app closed or go into background. Because when app go background the persisted operations are not running in the UIViewController.